# Create an iframe in body using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am facing a bit problem. I want to create an iframe inside the div tag which will be inside my body tag. I tried the following jQuery code:

```
$(document.createElement('<div id="modalDiv"><iframe id="modalIFrame" width="100%" height="100%" marginWidth="0" marginHeight="0" frameBorder="0" scrolling="auto" title="Dialog Title"></iframe></div>'));
```

But i didn't get any result. Also, i placed the script in the body tag but didn't get any result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have jQuery added:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').append('<div id="modalDiv"><iframe id="modalIFrame" width="100%" height="100%" marginWidth="0" marginHeight="0" frameBorder="0" scrolling="auto" title="Dialog Title"></iframe></div>');
});
```

This will add your code to the end of the body html...

Comment: To add to what chrisbradbury has said, what your code was doing was just creating an element, but not actually doing anything with it. Chris's example actually adds (appends) the HTML to the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

`createElement`'s argument needs to be a string containing the name of an element type. You are providing a fragment of HTML.

Since you are using jQuery, just construct a jQuery object from that string.

```
jQuery('<div id="modalDiv"><iframe id="modalIFrame" width="100%" height="100%" marginWidth="0" marginHeight="0" frameBorder="0" scrolling="auto" title="Dialog Title"></iframe></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.createElement()` doesn't support creating elements from HTML strings, but you can pass the string to jQuery to build out the content, i.e.:

```
var newContent = $('<div id="modalDiv"><iframe id="modalIFrame" width="100%" height="100%" marginWidth="0" marginHeight="0" frameBorder="0" scrolling="auto" title="Dialog Title"></iframe></div>');
newContent.appendTo("body");
```

Be sure to update the selector to whatever makes sense for you, here it's just being added to the `body` element.

Also, if the iframe is meant to actually point to a resource, be sure to set the `src` attribute as well.

Hope that helps! Cheers.